# How to parse an XML in SQL when the structure of the file is changing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have the following XML structure in a column ( that is just a small portion of it):

```xml
<block name="decision">
  <subdictionary name="main">
    <v id="Profit">126.45</v>
    <v id="Check">-99999.00</v>
    <v id="RulePath">PD159</v>
    <v id="ID">3256423</v>
    <v id="Outcome">RejectFinal</v>
    <v id="RP">,PD159</v>
  </subdictionary>
</block>
```

What I am trying to do is parse the result for "Outcome", but the problem for me is that for each different xml file the postion of "Outcome" can change.
What I have been trying so far is this

```sql
SELECT
    a.XmlResponse.value('(/decisiondocument/block[3]/subdictionary[1]/v)[@Outcome]', 'nvarchar(20)') 'Outcome'
FROM table
```

but it gives the following error:

> XQuery [Table_Request.XmlResponse.value()]: 'value()' requires a
>   singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type
>   'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

The desired result will be something like this:

```
 Column    Outcome
    1      RejectFinal
    2      Approved
    3      RejectFinal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this xpath. It'll match all `v` elements where `id` attribute matches "Outcome":

```
SELECT
    a.XmlResponse.value('(//v[@id="Outcome"])[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM t
```